# Checking for solo nodes in LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

How do I determine if a tag is of this format: `<Closed />` in Linq To XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [XElement.IsEmpty property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.isempty.aspx). Be aware of what `IsEmpty` checks for as defined by the note on the linked MSDN page:

> Note that an element that contains a
>   start and end tag with no content
>   between the tags is not considered to
>   be an empty element. It has content
>   with no length. Only an element that
>   contains only a start tag, and is
>   expressed as a terminated empty
>   element, is considered to be empty.

To illustrate, consider the following example:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(@"<root>
    <pair>foo</pair>
    <pair></pair>
    <single id=""42"" />
    <single />
</root>");

foreach (var element in xml.Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", element.IsEmpty, element);
}

// False: <pair>foo</pair>
// False: <pair></pair>
// True: <single id="42" />
// True: <single />
```

If you want to check that a node `IsEmpty` and also has no attributes, add a check for `element.Attributes().Any()` being `false`.